# difference between script shell on linux and script shell on solaris

Tags: linux, shell, unix, solaris

I want to learn shell scripting and I will use solaris in my work. Is there any difference between shell scripts on linux and shell scripts on solaris?

Comment: The default shell in most versions of Linux and Solaris (as well as mac's OSX) is _bash_. Most stuff will be the same. You can also write scripts in perl or python, which also should be available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is not between Linux and Solaris, the difference is between which shell you are using on each: sh, csh, ksh, zsh, bash etc.

When you write a shell script you should always start it with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) indicating what shell the script is written for.  For example
`#!/bin/bash`
or
`#!/bin/csh`

Note *shebang* also works for scripting in non-shell languages:
`#!/usr/bin/perl`
`#!/usr/bin/python`

The `bash` shell is now commonly available nearly everywhere, and I suggest that's the one you learn if it's available on you Solaris system.
`/bin/sh` is the *POSIX* shell and you should learn that, and the differences between it and bash.

`ksh` is an improvement over `sh`, as is `zsh` (but zsh claims it *"is a shell designed for interactive use"*)

[`csh`](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) is [considered](http://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/anti/csh/) [evil](http://lists.svlug.org/archives/svlug/1998-July/002390.html)

These days *bash* and *sh* are the ones to learn.

Comment: *`/bin/sh` is the POSIX shell...*  Be careful.  Because Linux tends to entirely conflate `sh` and `bash` - `sh` may even be softlinked directly to `bash`.  Solaris doesn't do that. Many are the Linux "`sh`" scripts that fail on Solaris because of bashisms.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all. 
What I understood from your replies that I have to learn the bash shell which is compatible with linux and solaris.

Comment: Your conclusion is right, but you should say thank you by accepting the answer of @stephen.